# Next(err) handler message in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I am new to error handling in express and I have a simple piece of code like so -

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const app = express();

let url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((err,req,res,next) => {
    console.log(`The error message is ${err}`)
    res.status(err.httpStatusCode).send('SOMETHING BROKE!');
})

app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    MongoClient.connect(url,function(error,client){
        if(error){
            error.httpStatusCode = 500;
            return next(error);
        }
        res.send('Connected successfully!');
    })
})
```

I have switched off connection to mongodb,so this fails. The error is shown and the app doesn't crash but I don't get "SOMETHING BROKE" or the console.log() part as expected from my express error handler. Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put error handling middleware at last
[Express error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

```
app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    MongoClient.connect(url,function(error,client){
        if(error){
            error.httpStatusCode = 500;
            return next(error);
        }
        res.send('Connected successfully!');
    })
})

app.use((err,req,res,next) => {
    console.log(`The error message is ${err}`)
    res.status(err.httpStatusCode).send('SOMETHING BROKE!');
})
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a bunch! So the error handler has to be always present at the last?

Comment: yes the default error-handling middleware function should added at the end of the middleware function stack.

Comment: Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `next(err)` in Express, that dispatches to the default Express error handler which isn't anything pretty.

But, what you would normally do is provide your own error handler which looks like this:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  // send your own custom error response here
  res.status(somethingAppropriate).send("something here");
});
```

You can read about this type of Express error handling [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers) in the Express doc.  These are a specific type of middleware with the four arguments instead of the usual three and with the `err` argument first.  It also **needs to go last in your definitions of routers and middleware** (so it's processed last).

---

You also don't have to centralize your error handling.  I find that many times, I want to send an error that is very specific to the context in which the error occured.  In that case, I just catch the error in the route handler where it occurred and send the error response from right here.

For example, you might do this:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    MongoClient.connect(url,function(error,client){
        if(error){
            res.status(500).send("Database offline - notify system administrator or please try back shortly");
        } else {
            res.send('Connected successfully!');
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Err,I have put the error handler. It's just that I was using the code piece at the beginning of my get requests,so it was not working. I switched it to the end of the code as suggested by @Azad and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @SushmitChakraborty - Please note the other option I added to the end of my answer.  I actually find this more useful than the generic error handler at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the tip,appreciate it. I just wanted to make a centralized error handler because it's a rather small project,but I'll keep that in mind.